# App.MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store) crashing on xamarin forms ios 13.1

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

When running xamarin forms project on iphone simulator with VS 2019 - Crashes when trying to initialise local store. It works no problem with Android.

```
await App.MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
```

This is the output

```
2019-10-15 11:24:02.309108+0100 RangeFinder.iOS[22896:377362] *** Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3899.22.15/UIApplication.m:4234
```

**Native Crash Reporting**

Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.

**Native stacktrace:**

```
0x109d16f05 - /Users/karlgibney/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F7C1809-51A7-466D-83B1-F74FFF7E9E96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BCB6227-DAF1-4834-8664-A496C7AACC61/RangeFinder.iOS.app/RangeFinder.iOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x109d0ae45 - /Users/karlgibney/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F7C1809-51A7-466D-83B1-F74FFF7E9E96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BCB6227-DAF1-4834-8664-A496C7AACC61/RangeFinder.iOS.app/RangeFinder.iOS : mono_handle_native_crash
    0x109d1e181 - /Users/karlgibney/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F7C1809-51A7-466D-83B1-F74FFF7E9E96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BCB6227-DAF1-4834-8664-A496C7AACC61/RangeFinder.iOS.app/RangeFinder.iOS : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler_debug
    0x7fff518c5b5d - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : _sigtramp
    0x109db9e79 - /Users/karlgibney/Library
/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F7C1809-51A7-466D-83B1-F74FFF7E9E96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BCB6227-DAF1-4834-8664-A496C7AACC61/RangeFinder.iOS.app/RangeFinder.iOS : mono_class_get_checked
    0x109d09cee - /Users/karlgibney/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F7C1809-51A7-466D-83B1-F74FFF7E9E96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BCB6227-DAF1-4834-8664-A496C7AACC61/RangeFinder.iOS.app/RangeFinder.iOS : mono_handle_exception_internal
    0x109d08dc9 - /Users/karlgibney/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F7C1809-51A7-466D-83B1-F74FFF7E9E96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BCB6227-DAF1-4834-8664-A496C7AACC61/RangeFinder.iOS.app/RangeFinder.iOS : mono_handle_exception
    0x109c8a16f - /Users/karlgibney/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F7C1809-51A7-466D-83B1-F74FFF7E9E96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BCB6227-DAF1-4834-8664-A496C7AACC61/RangeFinder.iOS.app/RangeFinder.iOS : mono_amd64_throw_exception
    0x10cd755b0 - Unknown
    0x109f6d713 - /Users/karlgibney/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F7C1809-51A7-466D-83B1-F74FFF7E9E96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BCB6227-DAF1-4834-8664-A496C7AACC61/RangeFinder.iOS.app/RangeFinder.iOS : _ZL17exception_handlerP11NSException
    0x7fff23baa64d - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __
handleUncaughtException
    0x7fff50864d76 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib : _ZL15_objc_terminatev
    0x7fff4f6dfe97 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib : _ZSt11__terminatePFvvE
    0x7fff4f6dfe39 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib : _ZSt9terminatev
    0x7fff516ad795 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : _dispatch_client_callout
    0x7fff516b0199 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : _dispatch_block_invoke_direct
    0x7fff3652c49e - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
    0x7fff3652c18c - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible]
    0x7fff3652c69b - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Private
Frameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]
    0x7fff23b0d271 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
    0x7fff23b0d19c - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopDoSource0
    0x7fff23b0c974 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopDoSources0
    0x7fff23b0767f - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Dev
eloper/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopRun
    0x7fff23b06e66 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    0x7fff38346bb0 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices : GSEventRunModal
    0x7fff47578dd0 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIAppl
icationMain
    0x111b8b0a2 - Unknown
    0x111b8adf3 - Unknown
    0x1112627e3 - Unknown
    0x109d21565 - /Users/karlgibney/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F7C1809-51A7-466D-83B1-F74FFF7E9E96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BCB6227-DAF1-4834-8664-A496C7AACC61/RangeFinder.iOS.app/RangeFinder.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x109e4d877 - /Users/karlgibney/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F7C1809-51A7-466D-83B1-F74FFF7E9E96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BCB6227-DAF1-4834-8664-A496C7AACC61/RangeFinder.iOS.app/RangeFinder.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x109e53cfc - /Users/karlgibney/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F7C1809-51A7-466D-83B1-F74FFF7E9E96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BCB6227-DAF1-4834-8664-A496C7AACC61/RangeFinder.iOS.app/RangeFinder.iOS : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked
    0x109c811b2 - /Users/karlgibney/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F7C1809-51A7-466D-83B1-F74FFF7E9E96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BCB6227-DAF1-4834-8664-A496C7AACC61/RangeFinder.iOS.ap
p/RangeFinder.iOS : mono_jit_exec
    0x109f7ecee - /Users/karlgibney/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F7C1809-51A7-466D-83B1-F74FFF7E9E96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BCB6227-DAF1-4834-8664-A496C7AACC61/RangeFinder.iOS.app/RangeFinder.iOS : xamarin_main
    0x109c3bc37 - /Users/karlgibney/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F7C1809-51A7-466D-83B1-F74FFF7E9E96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BCB6227-DAF1-4834-8664-A496C7AACC61/RangeFinder.iOS.app/RangeFinder.iOS : main
    0x7fff516ecd29 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : start
    0x3 - Unknown
```

**Basic Fault Address Reporting**

```
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x109dfffe4):0x109dfffd4  8b 47 1c 5d c3 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 55 48 89 e5  .G.]....
....UH..
0x109dfffe4  8b 47 20 a9 00 00 00 02 75 0c a9 00 00 00 10 75  .G .....u......u
0x109dffff4  26 48 8b 07 5d c3 48 8d 3d 9c 59 22 00 48 8d 35  &H..].H.=.Y".H.5
0x109e00004  8b 0a 24 00 48 8d 0d ff 0a 24 00 ba 79 03 00 00  ..$.H....$.
.y...
```

**Managed Stacktrace:**

```
at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain <0x00251>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x000b2>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x00132>
      at RangeFinder.iOS.Application:Main <0x00092>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_object <0x00352>
```

Comment: Hi , which version of Xamarin Forms or VS 2029 , they all need to update the latest version. Then you can have a try again .

Comment: Im running the latest versions. VS 2019 v16.3.5 & Xamarin Forms v4.2.0.848062

Comment: Thanks for replying ,you can submit in [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues) as an issue .Then we can follow it up in GitHub .

Answer (score 0):

We were getting this too, and we fixed it.  We are on VS Mac 8.3.5 (build 13) with XF 4.1.0.673156.

As we started to troubleshoot we noticed the call to `NavAsync` from `App.xaml.cs` to `Main.Xaml.cs` was failing because one of our libraries didn't `Init()` in the `AppDelegate.cs`.

When we went into the `AppDelegate` I noticed we didn't `Init()` `FFImageCache` but more importantly, the `Init()` call was happening after the
`LoadApplication(new App(new iOSInitializer()));` call.

I moved all the `Init()` calls to before the LoadApplication and everything worked!